# How to merge 2 pandas dataframes?

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
        'col0': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
        'col1': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({
        'col0': ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F','A'],
        'col1': ['aa', 'kk', 'cc','bb' ,'nn']})
```

How to merge them so that I get:

```
    col0    col1
0   A   aa, nn
1   B   bb,kk
2   C   cc
3   E   cc
4   F   bb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and aggregate `join`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .drop_duplicates()
        .groupby('col0')['col1']
        .agg(','.join)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  col0   col1
0    A  aa,nn
1    B  bb,kk
2    C     cc
3    E     cc
4    F     bb
```

Comment: Could have a look at this quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63848469/12639079 @jezrael